# How to pass dynamic schema names to Liquibase changeset and run them in a loop using liquibase gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, liquibase, dsl, liquibase-hibernate

We are new to liquibase and trying to create schema's dynamically like this

```
<property name="schemaName" value="temp2"/>
<changeSet author="abcd" id="1">
    <sql dbms="postgresql" endDelimiter=";">
        CREATE SCHEMA $(schemaName)
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

But we are getting this exception when we try to execute

```
    Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
  Position: 15 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE SCHEMA $(schemaName)]
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set src/main/db/changelog2.xml::1::aditya:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
  Position: 15 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE SCHEMA $(schemaName)]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:646)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1223)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:209)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

It would be of great help if the community could  please point us right direction

Comment: Please don't put images in your question, if they clearly be more useable as text.  No one can search your image or copy something out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replaceable parameters in your changelog - these are called [changelog parameters](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html)

The syntax is to use `${parameterName}` in the changelog (note curly braces rather than parentheses).

Comment: Did you mean [property substitution](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html)?

Comment: Property substitution and changelog parameters are similar - please check the manual for each to see which one better suits your use case.